# mysql entry alteration

Tags: mysql

I need to change the entry in column from `00-00-0000 to 07/02/1999`
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [standard ISO-8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

For your problem, hope this helped

```
select date_format(cast('1999/02/07' as date), '%d/%m/%Y');
```

your schema

```
select date_format(your_column), '%d/%m/%Y') ...
```

If you look for update, 1st answer is what you need

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant something else entirely, but as it is phrased, the answer to your question is a query of the form:

```
UPDATE the_table SET the_column = "07/02/1999" WHERE the_column = "00-00-000"
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also do it in a script side, whatever your script language you have one function similar to **explode()** in **PHP**.

`$pieces = explode ('/', $date);`

then re-join again using `'-'`

something like this `$newDate = $pieces[0] . '-' . $pieces[1] . '-' . $pieces[2];`

Comment: Thanks Fernando, but i need to do it purely in msql.